# How to pass an array of objects to multipart/form-data?

Tags: yaml, multipartform-data

I'm trying to pass an array of objects like this but I'm getting an Error:
'"type: object" is forbidden here'.

```
requestBody:
                required: true
                content:
                    multipart/form-data:
                        schema:
                            type: object
                            additionalProperties: false
                            required:
                              - posts
                            properties:
                                posts:
                                    type: array
                                    items:
                                        type: object
                                        properties:
                                            id:
                                                type: integer
                                            url:
                                                type: string
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your question needs a little bit more information. To get a good answer you can improve it. Would be good to mention that this is an OpenAPI (Swagger) specification, as well as provide an example of data that you are sending. As far as I can see, the spec itself looks okay, except perhaps some inconsistent indentation.